# How can I recover an administrative user account that I changed to root?

Tags: command-line, permissions, data-recovery, chown

I am new to Linux (Ubuntu) and was busy installing some applications, when I was told by the system that I needed root access.

`sudo` did not work.

So (And I think I understand the error of my ways now) I changed that user to root, at least that's what I thought I did, via `sudo chown -R root:root /username`. [not a 100% sure about that command line, it was about 5 days ago that I did this]

Can I recover that account and all of its settings?

Can I maybe revert the system to a state before the change?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `/username` directory - did you mean `/home/username`?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Was wondering why is said could not find the file.

Answer (score 1):

chown is used to change the ownership of files it doesn't change the user account. In the users home directory , /username in this case, there will be lots of files and folders beginning with . which will contain settings.

Your command has changed all files in /username to be owned by root , this was not a good idea, root typically can access anything so this wasn't needed.

Because all the files in that users home dir are owned by root that user wont be able to write and their login will fail.

To revert the situation you can just run chown again to change the files back to being owned by the user , you just need to know the user and group names for that user.

```
sudo chown -R user:group /username
```

When you are learning linux and not requiring heavy security its always a good idea to have a spare admin account that is otherwise unused on hand to fix things incase you break your normal account.

Comment: Yes, slowly getting the gist of things. I have now reassigned that folder to the original  owner and group, which is administrator [thank you for the assistance Arronical]

The problem I am facing is that after I changed the settings, of the account related to the username, i could no longer login as that user. The user is still available, as in I can change to that user in terminal, but I want to be able to log back into the environment that that user had before

Comment: which settings did you change and which tool did you use ?